# Usage of innodb and myisam tables together

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, myisam

I have a software that writes logs to the database and these logs will be stored about 2-3 months. A few people want to query these logs at any time they want. System writes avg 5000 rows per second (1000 bulk inserts) and primary key doesn't exist but there are 6 indexes for different columns. By the way, table has 20 columns and there is not any foreign key.

Because of huge disk sizes necessity, i don't want to use innodb tables. As you know MyISAM table sizes are about three (or more) times smaller than same innodb tables. I plan to use different tables per month and compress tables that are older than this month. Compressing is more easy for myisam tables than innodb using myisampack utility. For these reasons, i want to use myisam tables.

But we know myisam is not safe for corruption. I don't want to lose myisam tables if they are corrupted. It directed me to use innodb for real time logs. After a short period (5 minutes or 1 hour or at the midnight) i want to put my records to myisam tables. But converting table using "alter table ... engine=myisam" command takes much time for huge data.

I can use different databases and replicate innodb data to myisam table, this is one alternative. But i had some problems for replication before and i am not sure to use it. Other option i think is writing records double (both innodb and myisam tables at the same time). But it will be slow down both query and disk performances.

What do you suggest me about this situation? It can be engine conversion suggestions or fully new architecture suggestions.

Thanks,
Selim

Comment: Mysql is no ideal for huge amount of logging, you might need to consider other technology that allow bulk insert, and search at the same time, such as nosql.

Comment: @ajreal i also think like you but there is not enough time to learn and use nosql products in our production environment. I have mysql know-how but no nosql know-how!

Comment: how about archive storage engine in mysql? this engine is designed to store huge amount of data `The ARCHIVE storage engine is used for storing large amounts of data without indexes in a very small footprint.`, but is not ideal for searching

Comment: Thanks for ARCHIVE engine suggestion. But all logs can be searchable by max 50 users and must not take too much time. Searchs without indexes are poor for ARCHIVE engine. By the way, i plan to store older data in compressed myisam tables that can re-indexed after compression. This is one of the most important issues for me to use myisam tables.